# ios SWRevealViewController pop from rear to front

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have the following storyboard using SWRevealViewController.

[image]

The idea is I can navigate to a screen either from a homeVC which is a 'front' SWRevalVC or from the menuVC which is a 'rear' SWRevealVC.

When I get to 'MyAnotherVC' and tap on the back button, I want to always go to 'MYHomeVC'. However, if I have navigated there through 'MyMenyVC' there is currently no way to go to other view controller.

I guess this can easily be hacked in many ways, but I would like to know if there is a simple and efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Delete UINavigation that before my AntherVC

Comment: Have you got any answer?

Comment: same issue.....