# How to add back button, which will be pop to front view, to all menu items in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

i'm new in ios development.

I use SWRevealViewController to add back side menu in my app.
I want to add back button to each view in Menu.
**When I  tap on the back button, I want to always go to initial(MainTabbedView) view**.

Ui flow :

-->MainTabbedVIew-->**(toggle_menu)**-->**(select Item1)**-->Item 1-->**(Back pressed)**-->MainTabbedView

I found a similar question , [ios SWRevealViewController pop from rear to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655090/ios-swrevealviewcontroller-pop-from-rear-to-front), but it is still has no answer.

I added a button to view and write some code :

```
@IBAction func backPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainTabbedScreen") as UIViewController!
    self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

It works, but controller always recreated, 
for example: in TabBarController selected tab always resets.

I want to add NavigationController behavior(pop previous view) to SWRevealViewController menu items.

My storyboard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW4Rw.png

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
In my application , I began to use MMDrawerController instead  of SWRevealViewController
I use UINavigationController as central ViewController , and  when Menu click occurs id call

`pushViewController(controller,animated: true)`

my AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var backSideController:MMDrawerController?
var roorNavigationController:UINavigationController?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var rootController = self.window!.rootViewController
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil);
    var centerContent = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Center") as! UIViewController
    var left = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Left") as! Left
    var right = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Right") as! Right
    roorNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerContent)
    backSideController = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: roorNavigationController, leftDrawerViewController: left,rightDrawerViewController: right)
    backSideController!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView

    backSideController!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView
    window!.rootViewController=backSideController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
func pushController(controller: UIViewController){
    self.roorNavigationController?.pushViewController(controller,animated: true)
    self.backSideController!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And somewhere in MyMenuController :

```
@IBAction func pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    var newController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("About") as! About
    var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.pushController(newController)

}
```